# how to evaluate $\int_{5 n \pi}^{\frac{5\pi (n^2 + 1)}{n}}\frac{\frac{8 n^2 x}{25}dx}{((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) cos\frac{2 n x}{5})^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> $$\int_{5 n \pi}^{\frac{5\pi (n^2 + 1)}{n}}\frac{\frac{8 n^2 x}{25}dx}{((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) cos\frac{2 n x}{5})^2}$$
> for $n   \in \mathbb{N}\space\space\text{and } a,b >0$

I know this problem has to be solved by properties of definite integrals. so the first thing I tried was.

$$\frac{1}{k}\cdot\int_{ak}^{bk}f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)dx$$
so by $k=\frac{2n}{5}$

$$\frac{5}{2n}\int_{2\pi n^2 }^{2\pi (n^2 + 1)}\frac{\frac{4nx}{5}dx}{((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) cosx)^2}$$
$$\frac{5}{2n}\cdot\frac{4n}{5}\int_{2\pi n^2 }^{2\pi (n^2 + 1)}\frac{xdx}{((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) cosx)^2}$$
$$2\int_{2\pi n^2 }^{2\pi (n^2 + 1)}\frac{xdx}{(a^2(1+cosx) + b^2(1-cosx))^2}$$

now I have no clue how to solve it further. The function has no period nor did the  Weierstrass Substitution work did I mess up at any point? or was my entire method wrong? Kindly help me.

PS: It's a high school-level problem.
$$\text{Solution: }\frac{\pi^2(2n^2+1)(a^2+b^2)}{4a^3b^3}$$

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: oh yes! my bad let me add that part of the question 1 sec

Comment: Now I think it can be solved by substitution $u=2(n^2+1)\pi-x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the wonderful idea of xpaul, we have $I=(2n^2+1)\pi J$. For completeness, I shall find the easier integral
$$
\begin{aligned}
J & =\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d x}{\left(\left(a^2(1+\cos x)+b^2(1-\cos x\right)\right)^2} \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{\left(a^2 \cos ^2 x+b^2 \sin ^2 x\right)^2} \quad (\textrm{By  half-angle formula})\\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{\left(a^2 \cos ^2 x+b^2 \sin ^2 x\right)^2} \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^4 x}{\left(a^2+b^2 \tan ^2 x\right)^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting $\tan x =\frac{a}{b}\tan \theta$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
J & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1+\frac{a^2}{b^2} \tan ^2 \theta}{a^4 \sec ^4 \theta} \frac{a}{b} \sec ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{a^3 b} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^2 \theta d \theta+\frac{1}{a b^3} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{a^3 b} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1+\cos 2 \theta}{2} d \theta+\frac{a}{b^3} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1-\cos 2 \theta}{2} d \theta \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4 a^3 b}+\frac{\pi}{4a b^3} \\
& =\frac{\left(a^2+b^2\right) \pi}{4a^3 b^3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting back yields the answer
$$
\boxed{I=\frac{\pi^2\left(2 n^2+1\right)\left(a^2+b^2\right)}{4a^3 b^3}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but wouldn't it be $2n^2 + 1$ in the final square?

Comment: I think your $J$  is twice what it should be. For example, in the case $a=b$ the integral should be $\frac{\pi}{2a^4}$.

Comment: J.G. you are right!  Thank you very much.  Fixed, have a look.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $2(n^2+1)\pi-x\to x$ and then
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_{2\pi n^2 }^{2\pi (n^2 + 1)}\frac{xdx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2}\\
&=&\int^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{(2(n^2+1)\pi-x)dx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2}\\
&=&\int^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{2(n^2+1)\pi dx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2}-\int^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{x dx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2}. 
\end{eqnarray}
Let
$$ J=\int^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{dx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2}.$$
which can be solved easily. For the second one, let
$$ K = \int^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{x dx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2} \tag 1. $$
After the substitution $2\pi -x\to x$,
$$ K = \int^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{(2\pi -x) dx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2} \tag 2. $$
(1)+(2) gives
$$ K=\pi\int^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{dx}{(a^2(1+\cos x) + b^2(1-\cos x))^2}  =\pi J. $$
So
$$ I=2(n^2+1)\pi J-\pi J=(2n^2+1)\pi J. $$

Comment: How did you think of this substitution? What motivated you for this?

Comment: For $\int_0^{2\pi}xf(\cos(x))dx$, $2\pi-x\to x$ works.

Comment: Is this kind of a universal sub?

Comment: Just this type of integrals.

Comment: I'm sorry for such a dumb question but wouldn't the limits of integration be $\int_{2\pi}^{0}$ ?

Comment: You can change $\int_{2\pi}^0$ into $-\int_0^{2\pi}$.

Comment: yes, but wouldn't that affect the order to $K - J$ ?

Comment: xpaul, should the last line be $I=(2n^2+1)\pi J$?

Comment: Nice solution (+1)

Comment: @Lai, yes, you'er right.